# JQuery Dimmer and No Scrolling wont work together

Tags: jquery, html, css

When my website is in Mobile view I have a Hamburger menu which I toggle on and off with JQuery.  This works fine but to bring more focus to this I have tried to add a dimmer effect to the Main content and also tried to prevent scrolling to the Main content when the Hamburger menu is shown. However when I do this I can get either the dimmer working or the no scrolling to work individually (if I comment out one or the other) but for some reason they don't work when combined and I don't know why (as below). Also when doing just the no scrolling it jumps to the bottom of the body which I would prefer not to be the case. I am fairly new to JQuery so if what I have done could be condensed or made better please let me know.

JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#toggle-nav').click(function (e) {
event.stopPropagation();
jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
jQuery('.hamburgerWrapper').toggleClass('active');

//Dimmer
jQuery('.dimmer').toggleClass('active');

//No Scrolling
jQuery('.main').toggleClass('no-scrolling');

e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

CSS:

```
.main
{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainWrapper
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: white;
    flex: 1;    
}

/*NAVIGATION MENUS*/
.nav
{
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navWrapper
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

/*HORIZONTAL MENU*/
.menu
{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu ul.navList
{
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: -60%;
  background: blue;
  min-width: 60%;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu ul.active {
  left: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.menu > ul > li > a
{
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    padding:16px 16px 12px 16px;
    border-bottom:4px solid transparent; /*To offset white underline hover*/
    font-weight: 700;
}

.menu > ul > li a:hover
{
    background-color: green;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #F1F227;
    color: #C5EFF7;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}

/*HAMBURGER*/
.hamburgerWrapper
{
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
    z-index: 2;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.hamburgerWrapper.active
{
    left: 60%;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.hamburger
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.hamburger li a
{
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    padding:16px 16px 15px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#toggle-nav:after {
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: 'Menu';
}

#toggle-nav span, #toggle-nav span:before, #toggle-nav span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#toggle-nav span:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px; 
}
#toggle-nav span:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
}

#toggle-nav span, #toggle-nav span:before, #toggle-nav span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#toggle-nav.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#toggle-nav.active span:before, #toggle-nav.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#toggle-nav.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#toggle-nav.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/*Sub Menu*/
.menu > ul > li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

.submenu
{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    background-color: blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width : 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.submenu > li > a
{
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    padding:16px 16px 12px 26px;
    border-bottom:4px solid transparent; /*To offset white underline hover*/
    font-weight: 500;
}

.submenu > li:hover > a
{
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFDB00;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #F1F227;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

/*Child Sub Menu*/
.menu > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul 
{
    display: block;
}

.subSubmenu
{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    background-color: blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    bottom: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.subSubmenu > li > a
{
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    padding:19px 16px 12px 36px;
    border-bottom:4px solid transparent; /*To offset white underline hover*/
    font-weight: 300;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > a
{
  background-color: green;
  color: #C5EFF7;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #F1F227;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

   /*set up the right arrows first*/
   .menu li > a:after { content: ' \25B6'; }

   /*set up the downward arrow for top level items*/
   .menu > ul > li > a:after {content: ' \25BC'; }

   /*clear the content if a is only child*/
   .menu li > a:only-child:after {content: ''; }

/*Dimmer to dim background and no scolling when Hamburger menu is shown*/
.dimmer {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: none;
}

.dimmer.active 
{
  display: block;
}

.no-scrolling 
{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="nav">
<div class ="navWrapper">
<nav role="navigation" class="menu">  
    <div class="hamburgerWrapper">
        <ul class="hamburger">
    <li><a id="toggle-nav" href="#"><span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="navList">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="MainPage.aspx">Menu 3</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>  
        <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 4</a>   
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="hamburgerWrapper">
          <div class="toggle-nav"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="dimmer"></div> 

<div class="main">
<main role ="main" class="mainWrapper">
</main>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Javascript/JavaScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post your markup so we have a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Sorry Michael, I thought what I posted concerning JQuery and No-scrolling would be okay. Here is a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/k9sws5ja/) and I have added some more code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by applying the no-scrolling element and Jquery to the Body and not the main. I'm not overly sure why it does not work against th Main but it now works as intended anyhow. The parts of the code that I changed are as follows:

CSS:

```
body.no-scrolling 
{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

JQuery:

```
    //No Scrolling
    jQuery('body').toggleClass('no-scrolling');
```